# How to avoid ggplot grouping within factors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <-tibble::tribble(
       ~tweet_id, ~user_id, ~favourite_count,
              1L,      "a",             100L,
              2L,      "b",             111L,
              3L,      "c",             126L,
              4L,      "a",              75L,
              5L,      "d",              73L,
              6L,      "e",              64L,
              7L,      "f",              22L,
              8L,      "f",              11L,
              9L,      "g",               9L,
             10L,      "h",               9L
       ) %>% 
  mutate(tweet_id = factor(tweet_id))
```

The desired output is a chart with 10 bars, with a bar representing `favourite_count` per each unique `tweet_id`, and with `user_id` as the label per bar on the chart. My issue is how to stop ggplot collapsing within `user_id`.

i.e. the chart should contain 10 bars, 1 per unique `tweet_id`, but something like this collapses within `user_id` so there are only 8 bars on the plot:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = favourite_count, y = reorder(user_id, favourite_count))) + 
  geom_col()
```

I thought one solution might be to make the plot using `tweet_id`, and then to replace the y-axis labels with values from `user_id`, but this results in the wrong ordering of values from `user_id`:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = favourite_count, y = reorder(tweet_id, favourite_count))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = df$user_id)
```

Any suggestions welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close enough, but you've to preserve the equal `user_id` in different labels, and reorder the new labels. You can "trick" `ggplot` in this way:

```
# create a vector of ordered labels of id
labs <- df[with(df, order(df$favourite_count)), ]$user_id

df %>% 
  # use the unique concatenation of user id and tweet id to preserve the diffent-equal
  # users that ggplot put together
  ggplot(aes(x = favourite_count, y = reorder(
                                             paste0(user_id,tweet_id),
                                             favourite_count))) + 
  geom_bar(stat ="identity") + 
  # add the ordered labels
  scale_y_discrete(labels= labs ) + 
  # give to y axis a readable name
  ylab("user_id")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> The desired output is a chart with 10 bars, with a bar representing
>   favourite_count per each unique tweet_id, and with user_id as the
>   label per bar on the chart.

Is it what you want?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <-tibble::tribble(
  ~tweet_id, ~user_id, ~favourite_count,
  1L,      "a",             100L,
  2L,      "b",             111L,
  3L,      "c",             126L,
  4L,      "a",              75L,
  5L,      "d",              73L,
  6L,      "e",              64L,
  7L,      "f",              22L,
  8L,      "f",              11L,
  9L,      "g",               9L,
  10L,      "h",               9L
) %>% 
  mutate(tweet_id = factor(tweet_id))


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = tweet_id, y = favourite_count, label = user_id)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + # "identity" to use the value of "favourite_count"
  geom_text() # add labels on each bar
```

Output :

[image]

[EDIT]

With your comment here is another idea, of course you can custom colors but this is not the point.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = reorder(user_id, -df$favourite_count), y = favourite_count, fill = tweet_id)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + # "identity" to use the value of "favourite_count"
  scale_x_discrete(name = "user_id")
```

output :

[image: more idea]

Comment: Thanks, but no, I'd like to remove the `tweet_id` labels altogether and replace them with the equivalent values from `user_id`, with the bars in descening order of `favourite_count`.

Comment: I have added an idea, I hope it is closer to what you want.

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that, but splitting users by tweet_id is a nice idea - many thanks!